# GUI Extension AddOn deployment Tridion Cloud 9.5

Tags: gui-extensions

I am working on GUI Extension and wrapping it with ADDON for deployment.

**Information :** This is a GUI Extension

```
          Type : UIEditor
          Deploying Using: http://domain/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=addon (UI Interface)
          Package : ZIP File
          Environment: On Premise for below Issue, Need to check procedure for Cloud
```

**Info Details:**
The Package is deployed successfully through the interface with the
status="success"

```
           It create the extension folder at "Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Editors" with all the 
           files and  folder including config. The manifest has ("assembliesFolder": 
           "Assemblies") set which contains the DLL File required for the extension . Manifest 
            file is shown below.
```

**Issue:** :

The problem is the deployed ADDOn failed to load the DLL and it is searching in
"\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin" for the DLL.

Once I upload a DLL on this path ADDOn
works as expected. So the issue here is the Manual Step involved in this Process and
All the other attributes in the "Manifest.json" are working except this attribute.

**Questions:**
Is this a standard Practice or I am doing something wrong here.?

When I tried to deploy the AddOn in Cloud Hosted CM it is showing "Pending Activation"
. So is there any other procedure we need to follow to deploy in the cloud?(might be
restricted)

**Option 1:**

**Manifest.json**

`{
"manifestVersion": "1.0",
"id": "Extensionname",
"version": "1.0",
"name": "GUI Extension",
"description": "GUI Extension",
"author": "xxx",
"requireConfiguration": "No",
"minVersion": "0.0.0.0",
"extensions": [
{
"name": "Extensionname",
"type": "UIEditor",
"properties": {
"name": "Extensionname",
"contentFolder": ".",
"configurationPath": "Config\xxx.config",
"assembliesFolder": "Assemblies",
"globalResourcesFolder": "Resources"
}
}
]
}`

**ZIP Package Contains**
[image]

**Option 2:**

`{
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "id": "XXXExtensions",
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "XXX GUI Extension",
  "description": "XX GUI Extension",
  "author": "Sachin Jain",
  "requireConfiguration": "No",
  "minVersion": "0.0.0.0",
  "extensions": [
    {
      "name": "XXXExtensions",
      "type": "UIEditor",
      "properties": {
        "name": "XXXExtensions",
        "contentFolder": "XXXExtensions",
        "configurationPath": "XXXExtensions\\Config\\XXX.config",
        "assembliesFolder": "XXXExtensions\\Assemblies",
        "globalResourcesFolder": "XXXExtensions\\Resources"
  }
}

]
}`

**ZIP Package Contains**
[image]

Comment: ContentFolder "." looks a little dodgy. Look at https://docs.rws.com/816112/694343/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/gui-editor-extension - the recommendation is use a containing folder alongside your manifest, e.g MyEditor - then the paths become relative to that, so MyEditor\\Edtior, MyEditor\\Editor\\Assemblies.

Comment: Hey Neil, Thanks for response.. "." is the root of zip , It picks the client/config/css/jss/generic etc which are at the same level of Assemblies  but unable to pick Assemblies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AddOn / Manifest is not forcing the creation of the required /somewhere/bin folder and moving the bin into the folder; this is being done manually in our DEV and will be done manually (or a separate script) in the Tridion Cloud environment for now.

Comment: This was resolved by the cloud team manually adding the referenced DLL into the filestore.

Comment: Does this mean this is a bug? The whole idea of the assembliesFolder is that DLLs in it will be loaded automatically, right?

Comment: To our findings, I would agree this appears to be a defect.

Comment: Manually moving definitely shouldn't be necessary. I checked an add-on I'd worked on that had additional assemblies and it is the same as the option 2 shown above and it works perfectly. The only difference I can see is that I dont use any "minVersion" in the manifest.

Comment: @Neil - are you using the RWS Cloud Instance or local version?

Comment: RWS Cloud, Sites 9.5

Answer (score 0):

Please validate if you included assembly reference to your aspx files
https://docs.rws.com/816112/722175/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/adding-a--net-assembly-reference-to-your-web-control-or-webpage